# WCF REST/JSON Service UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm trying to use basic authentication with my WCF Rest/JSON service.

Therefore I've create a class which derives from "UserNamePasswordValidator" and added it to my web.config.
In IIS only Basic Authentication is enabled.

Unfortunately this class is never called. When I call a rest method in my browser the dialog for entering the username and password is shown but nothing happens after that.

Here my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" 
         value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="myTimeMvc.Webservice.MyTimeRestService"
               behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
                  contract="myTimeMvc.Webservice.IMyTimeRestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="returnFaults">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <!--<serviceCertificate findValue="MyWebSite"
                                    storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                    storeName="My"
                                    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />-->
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="myTimeServiceDemoa.WcfExtension.CustomUserNameValidator,TestWcfServiceAuth" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here my CustomUserNameValidator.cs

```
namespace myTimeServiceDemoa.WcfExtension
{
 public class CustomUserNameValidator : System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator
{

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {

        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("You must provide both the username and password to access this service");
        }

        if (!(userName == "user1" && password == "test") && !(userName == "user2" && password == "test"))
        {

            throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");

        }
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE:
After two days of trying I give up now because I don't see what I may have done wrong. Seems this stuff is not working for me...
I investigated a lot and everything you need is to change Authentication of your WebApplication in IIS to "Basic" and add a custom "CustomUserNameValidator" in your web.config but this is not working!
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My solution:

1. Use "Anonymous Authentication" in IIS
2. Use a "ServiceAuthorizationManager" and check HTTP-Headers in "CheckAccessCore"

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Is `myTimeServiceDemoa.WcfExtension` the correct namespace?  Note that namespaces in C# are case-sensitive, so `my` is not the same as `My`, for example.

Comment: It is definaltely the correct namespace. It is working for "ServiceAuthorizationManager" because I just toogled these two by commenting out/in. They are in the same file with the same name. I updated my code anyway...